# Tomcat vs Glassfish, is jpa with both possible?

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

Hi i often read about this topic the following:

```
"Tomcat is a servlet container only, which simply means that it will not 
provide support for Java EE features."
```

JPA for example is a Java EE feature. Which means it is supported of Glassfish.
But i can also use JPA on a tomcat!

So why can i do that? 
I thought that i can just stick to Servlet/JSP with a tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA *is* part of Java EE, which means every Java EE container should support it. Tomcat does not support JPA out-of-the-box. You can use JPA in applications deployed on Tomcat only if these applications embed some JPA implementation.

Typically you'll find Spring applications with Hibernate or EclipseLink embedded, both providing JPA API. Tomcat is completely unaware of that, it's user code as far as he's concerned.

## See also

- [Tom EE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) - "*Java EE 6 Web Profile certification where Tomcat is top dog*"

Comment: Thank you.

So if i want to use JPA on my tomcat i have to use hibernate. Right?

Comment: @krackmoe: right, or any other JPA implementation. Notice that certified Java EE containers also need *some* implementation, it can be Hibernate underneath as well.

Comment: So without any implementation (e.g. hibernate..) i wont be able to use jpa?

Comment: @krackmoe: nope. The difference is that in Java EE container this implementation is bundled while in Tomcat you must distribute it yourself.

Comment: Sorry i dont want to annoy you. But what do you mean with "this implementation is bundled"?

Comment: @krackmoe: In Java EE certified container `hibernate.jar` (or whichever implementation they choose) is already in the containers libraries, available for all applications. In Tomcat you must add `hibernate.jar` to your `WAR` file (or add it to common libraries manually. Also Tomcat won't automatically bootstrap your JPA provider.

Comment: If some one has Tomcat+OpenJPA2.x may be interested in my personal automanaged EntityManager project. https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager